# How to retain the metadata information on clipped satellite image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, metadata, xml

I am new to QGIS. I am working with some satellite images XML format and processing in QGIS. I would like to retain the information of metadata of original images after clipping . The clipped images contained the TIF format and do not have the metadata information. How could I do that or any solution to process multi-images?

[image: The original image]

[image: The original image]

[image: File]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Can you describe how you clipped your satellite images ? It can help some users to reproduce your case.

Comment: I just processed by using Raster -> Extraction -> Clip raster by extent

Comment: "XML format" is a general text-based format for any information, not just satellite imagery - are there other files with the XML that contain the actual data values? Can you show us the "Properties" dialog of your image data when loaded into QGIS?

Comment: I've already edited my question to make clear.

Comment: Very useful! That tells us this is SPOT DIMAP format! https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/dimap.html

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the idea. What should I do with my new clipped image?